# How to authenticate to Cloud SQL Server using Active Directory

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, active-directory, google-cloud-sql

I’m looking for a way to authenticate on Cloud SQL Server using Microsoft Active Directory but I can’t find any specific way to achieve this? Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features#general_features_unavailable_for) this is not currently supported.

You can achieve this inside Google Cloud Platform by provisioning a SQL Server instance in Compute Engine as described in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/sql-server/creating-sql-server-instances), however, you will have to maintain your SQL Server instance.

I also found this [public feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/159948400) Which I recommend you to star and follow where other users are requesting this functionality